# TextBox inside Listview - getting ListViewItem on TextBox TextChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` that displays a few `TextBoxes`. For each `TextBox`, I am catching a `SelectionChanged` event.

My XAML file looks something like this:

```
<ListView>
    <GridView>
        ...
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox SelectionChanged="Box_SelectionChanged" />
        </DataTemplate>
        ...
    </GridView>
</ListView>
```

And my Xaml CS file looks like this:

```
private void Box_SelectionChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {}
```

In my `Box_SelectionChanged` function, I would like to get the `ListViewItem` in which the text box was updated.

How can I do so?

Comment: @Bob. - I have tried casting the sender as a TextBox to see if I can get the ListViewItem from that but had no luck

Comment: When you debug, what kind of object does sender show up as?

Comment: @Bob. It's of type `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`

Comment: Odd, that walking up the visual tree in the debugger, you couldn't find the ListView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

Add this method to your class:

```
public static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
        {
            UIElement parent = element; while (parent != null)
            {
                T correctlyTyped = parent as T; if (correctlyTyped != null)
                {
                    return correctlyTyped;
                }
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
            } return null;
        }
```

And in Box_SelectionChanged event handler invoke this method:

```
        private void Box_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {          
            var tmp = FindVisualParent<ListViewItem>(sender as TextBox);
        }
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is there a way of getting the parent through a property or method in the sender object or do I have to perform a search on the entire ListView every time?

Comment: You're welcome. You don't perform search on entire ListView, everytime when you invoke this method you're checking only 7 elements. You can check this in Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).